# Xamarin Android Error - Built Error

Tags: android, xamarin

I am making a ListView with click button open List View. When I rebuild it, everything is good with no error. But when I built in the simulation section, it reports an error. Does anyone help me to fix that please. Here my code which reported error:

> Error Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.

```
public class Screen1 : Activity
{

    private List<string> mItems;

    private ListView mListView;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Button clicknews = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnlist);

        mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.lstView);

        clicknews.Click += (object sender, EventArgs args) =>
        {               
            mItems = new List<string>();

            mItems.Add("Meal Plan");

            mItems.Add("Training Plan");

            ArrayAdapter<string> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, 

           Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems);

           mListView.Adapter = mAdapter;

        };

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.screen1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to call `SetContentView` **before** you call `FindViewByID`

Comment: It takes me 2 hours to find the error. But you do that in 1 second. It works now. Thanks so much

Comment: great, please use the green checkmark to flag this answer as Accepted